# Where to create a publicly-accessible log file on Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-external-storage

Our application has a large amount of C++ code that creates its own log file as a simple .txt file. It's a circular buffer so it's limited to the size we specify. It's also placed in whatever directory we specify.

The problem is where to place the file so it can be accessed with ADB or a similar tool (without rooting).  If we didn't care about the publicly-accessible part, it seems this would be the logical place to locate the file:

```
packageManager.getApplicationInfo(applicationContext.getPackageName().dataDir
```

But since we want to be able to pull the file from a customer's phone for post-mortem debugging, I've tried placing it here:

```
"/mnt/sdcard/Android/data"
```

This is problematic for several reasons, but I'm not sure if they're all true. (1) It's hard-coded; (2) Not all Android devices have external storage, although I thought they still mapped it to internal storage? (3) The location isn't app-specific so it won't get uninstalled along with the app. And (4) Runtime permission for EXTERNAL_STORAGE is required.

I believe 1-3 can be solved with something like:

```
android.content.Context.getExternalFilesDir()
```

Or is there a better choice?

But I don't believe this will get around #4, which is unfortunate as I'd prefer not to "scare" users with more permission requests.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Like many others you are confused about what `internal` and `external` means in regards to Android storage. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/150/storing-files-in-internal-external-storage/17144/android-internal-and-external-storage-terminology-clarification#t=201609292007145280414

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm fairly certain I understand the topic better now, but according to Google's documentation it still seems like I need to check the external storage state?  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: There is nothing contradictory about that. It's for those devices where `external` (i.e. public) storage is configured to use the removable media

Comment: So then I do need to also check "if (getExternalStorageState() == MEDIA_MOUNTED)" before proceeding?

Comment: yes. that would be a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the permissions to read and write the External SD using this code in the Manifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And then this string will give you the wanted path:

```
String directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/" + getContext().getPackageName();
```

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exemple.yourapp/

Comment: Thanks! Would I still need to use "if (getExternalStorageState() == MEDIA_MOUNTED)" prior to writing to that directory?  Also, would I actually need "/Android/data/" or just my package name on the end?

Comment: If you use the /Android/data/ folder then its content will be deleted on app uninstall, so you may want to use just the 'Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()' if you don't want that. You don't need to check because External Storage is NOT the SD card is the device internal storage.

Comment: So no way to get around the permissions check then? If there were a way to see inside the app's folder with ADB then I'd rather put the file there, but from what I've seen so far anyway, that's not possible.

Comment: what do you mean when you say apps folder? `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exemple.yourapp/` or `/data/data/com.exemple.yourapp/`

Comment: I mean the package manager 'dataDir' from my first line of code above. Don't recall the absolute path right now but I know I wasn't able to see files in there using ADB SHELL.

Comment: Using your method, I was given the absolute path of "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mycompany.appname". Unfortunately I am not allowed to Write there even though I do have permissions in my manifest.

Comment: if you are marshmallow then you need to request permission at runtime, I will give you the code in a second

Comment: Thanks, you can post the runtime permission code if you like but I've got that implemented. I think the problem is that my package name doesn't already exist as a sub-directory of ".../Android/data". I'll need to create that directory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124586/discussion-between-razvan-cristian-lung-and-bungles).